# PTAS & FPTAS definition

Tags: complexity-theory

I'm new to Optimization and aproximation problems

I would like to know if the following statements are true or false and why :

- If the optimization problem $K$ admits a PTAS then $K$ admits an approximation algorithm with
  approximation ratio 2.
- If there is an FPTAS for MIN-TSP then $P = NP$

Comment: For the first question, use the definition of PTAS.

Comment: In the definition is 1+ $\epsilon$ But here I do not understand why it is directly 2